# Android Listview with image and Array text

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to populate a listview with text taken from (string.xml) and images.
I did so but I get NPE
Can you help me?
thanks

```
public class Menu_activity extends ListActivity {
int[] img = { R.drawable.01, R.drawable.1, R.drawable.2,
        R.drawable.3, R.drawable.4,
        R.drawable.5};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setDividerHeight(1);
    getListView().setAdapter(new BindDataAdapter(this, img, men));

}
private String[] men = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.men);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
private String[] men;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    men = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.men); // inside onCreate
    getListView().setDividerHeight(1);
    getListView().setAdapter(new BindDataAdapter(this, img, men));     
}
```

Comment: Ah, good catch! I didn't notice it was outside of `onCreate()`. Do you need to use `setContentView()` before calling `getListView()`? I know its an Android `resource` but I was thinking it still needed to be set first...

Comment: CONFIRM, IT WORKS WELL

Comment: @codeMagic the docs  does not say anything about it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html. So it should work fine

Comment: Ah, yes, "ListActivity has a default layout..." I knew it had a default `ListView` but I guess I didn't realize it was in a default `layout`. Just checking...thanks

Comment: @codeMagic yes if he had custom lauout then op should have a listview with id `android:id="@android:id/list"` and `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)`